# META key mapped to fn+win key

Tags: kubuntu, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, shortcuts, kde5

So I have Kubuntu and I am trying to edit the Quick tile Window shortcuts in the KWin global shortcuts tab and everything is set to default (Meta + arrow key). Thats exactly what i want but I am running into an issue where my Meta key is tied to fn+win by default and I am having trouble figuring out how to change it to be mapped to just my win key. If it matters at all i have an Alienware m17 AWM17-7219SLV-PUS if theres a special keyboard thing (some people were saying some keyboards have a game mode which locks the fn key, but i do not see any such key on my keyboard.).

All of my setting are set to default. This is a fresh install (I was using fedora with kde but their new version broke a program i was working with so I just switched instead of waiting for updated support. It was having the same issues on fedora. I kinda just dealt with it but since im running a new os install i figured id set everything up at once).

I even went into my bios settings to change the fn key behavior and it still remains the same. Is there a way for me to change the mapping to just the win key? BTW my win key doesnt register when i try using the xev command but fn+win registers as super_r.

Comment: Still no luck figuring anything out. I noticed I didn't really describe what it's doing. It's like pressing fn+win puts my laptop in an active meta key state where after I activate it, I no longer need to hit the fn+win key to activate the meta key. After hitting them, I can freely use the arrow keys to quick tile my windows and any other meta shortcut. This stays active until I press win+fn which seems to switch it back to on off state. I can't find anything about this, all I find is people talking about the meta key not opening the application menus, which mine does fine with fn+win/alt+f1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who occurs an issue like this, fn+f6 is the cause of this issue. For whatever reason fn+f6 makes your super key require fn+win instead of just the win key. I have zero clue why this happens or for what reason but if anyone is using an alienware laptop (not sure if its all alienware or all dells) and runs into this issue, fn+f6 fixes this issue.

Does anyone know what the reason for this is or if this is a known thing and im just stupid... I've never owned a alienware until this laptop so Im still working on getting over dells quirks.